# How to save status of a table and show it after reload or new login

Tags: javascript, json, pagination

Have table with implemented pagination. Now I want to save it's status after reload, so it doensnt start every time
from the first page after every reload. I've heard about local sorage in browser but have no idea how to implement it in my case. as I understand I have to save localy the number of actual page and load it like my forst page: showPage(1); but instead "1" i need some variable that contenst information of last active page. can somebody help me with it?

```js
// Returns an array of maxLength (or less) page numbers
// where a 0 in the returned array denotes a gap in the series.
// Parameters:
//   totalPages:     total number of pages
//   page:           current page
//   maxLength:      maximum size of returned array
function getPageList(totalPages, page, maxLength) {
    if (maxLength < 5) throw "maxLength must be at least 5";

    function range(start, end) {
        return Array.from(Array(end - start + 1), (_, i) => i + start);
    }

    var sideWidth = maxLength < 9 ? 1 : 2;
    var leftWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 3) >> 1;// if pageination size=7: res = (7-1*2-3) = 9 and >> 1 = 4 (0,5 falls down)
    var rightWidth = (maxLength - sideWidth * 2 - 2) >> 1;// same like above
    if (totalPages <= maxLength) {
        // no breaks in list
        return range(1, totalPages);
    }
    if (page <= maxLength - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) { 
        // no break on left of page
        return range(1, maxLength - sideWidth - 1)
            .concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
    }
    if (page >= totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth) {
        // no break on right of page
        return range(1, sideWidth)
            .concat(0, range(totalPages - sideWidth - 1 - rightWidth - leftWidth, totalPages));
    }
    // Breaks on both sides
    return range(1, sideWidth)
        .concat(0, range(page - leftWidth, page + rightWidth),
            0, range(totalPages - sideWidth + 1, totalPages));
}








// Returns the ISO week of the date.
Date.prototype.getWeek = function (y) {
    var date = new Date(this.getTime());
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Thursday in current week decides the year.
    if (y == "2021" || y == "2022" || y == "2023" || y == "2027" || y == "2028" || y == "2033" || y == "2034" || y == "2038" || y == "2039" || y == "2044" || y == "2045" || y == "2049" || y == "2050") {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    }
    else {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    }
    // January 4 is always in week 1.
    var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
    return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
}

function getDateRangeOfWeek(weekNo, y) {
    var d1, numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday, i;
    var dates = [];

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        d1 = new Date('' + y + '');

        numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday = d1.getDay() - 1;
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday);
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + (7 * (weekNo - d1.getWeek(y))));
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + i);
        let item = d1.getDate() + "." + (d1.getMonth() + 1) + "." + d1.getFullYear();
        dates.push(item);
    }

    return dates;

};











var tableId = "Tabledta";


function LoadData() {
    var tab = $("<table  id=calendar class=MyTable border=1></table>");
    var thead = $("<thead></thead>");
    var tbody = $('<tbody id="jar"></tbody>');

    var theadrow = $("<tr/>")
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">FSE' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Monday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Tuesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Wednesday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Thursday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Friday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Saturday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    theadrow.append('<th style="padding:5px;font-weight:bold;">Sunday' + "&nbsp;" + '</th>');
    thead.append(theadrow);





    for (var i = 1; i < 521; i++) {

        var trow = $("<tr class=content/>").data("id", i);                                //.data("id", i, "class", "content");
        trow.append("<td>FSE" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td>Monday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td>Tuesday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td>Wednesday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td> Thursday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append(" <td>Friday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td>Saturday" + i + "</td>");
        trow.append("<td>Sunday" + i + "</td>");
        tbody.append(trow);
    }


    tab.append(thead);
    tab.append(tbody);
    $("#" + tableId).html(tab);
}



// Below is an example use of the above function.
$(function () {

    LoadData();
    

     let week = 1;

    $("#calendar tbody tr").each(function () {
        let count = $(this).index();
        if (count % 11 === 0) {
            let items = getDateRangeOfWeek(week, 2020);
            let newrow = "<tr class='content'><td></td><td>" + items[0] + "</td><td>" + items[1] + "</td><td>" + items[2] + "</td><td>" + items[3] + "</td><td>" + items[4] + "</td><td>" + items[5] + "</td><td>" + items[6] + "</td></tr>";
            if (count === 0) {
                $(newrow).insertBefore("#calendar tbody tr:eq(" + (count) + ")");
            }
            else{
                $(newrow).insertAfter("#calendar tbody tr:eq(" + (count - 1) + ")");
            }
            week += 1;
        }
    });

    // Number of items and limits the number of items per page
    var numberOfItems = $("#jar .content").length;
    var limitPerPage = 11;
    // Total pages rounded upwards
    var totalPages = Math.ceil(numberOfItems / limitPerPage);
    // Number of buttons at the top, not counting prev/next,
    // but including the dotted buttons.
    // Must be at least 5:
    var paginationSize = 7;
    var currentPage;

    function showPage(whichPage) {

        if (whichPage < 1 || whichPage > totalPages) return false;
        currentPage = whichPage;
        $("#jar .content").hide()
            .slice((currentPage - 1) * limitPerPage,
                currentPage * limitPerPage).show();
        // Replace the navigation items (not prev/next):            
        $(".pagination li").slice(1, -1).remove();
        getPageList(totalPages, currentPage, paginationSize).forEach(item => {
            $("<li>").addClass("page-item")
                .addClass(item ? "current-page" : "disabled")
                .toggleClass("active", item === currentPage).append(
                    $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                        href: "javascript:void(0)"
                    }).text(item || "...")
                ).insertBefore("#next-page");
        });
        // Disable prev/next when at first/last page:
        $("#previous-page").toggleClass("disabled", currentPage === 1);
        $("#next-page").toggleClass("disabled", currentPage === totalPages);
        return true;

    }

    // Include the prev/next buttons:
    $(".pagination").append(
        $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({ id: "previous-page" }).append(
            $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                href: "javascript:void(0)"
            }).text("Prev")
        ),
        $("<li>").addClass("page-item").attr({ id: "next-page" }).append(
            $("<a>").addClass("page-link").attr({
                href: "javascript:void(0)"
            }).text("Next")
        )
    );
    // Show the page links
    $("#jar").show();
    showPage(1);

    //$("#jar .content").hide()
    //    .slice((currentPage - 1) * limitPerPage,
    //        currentPage * limitPerPage).show();




    ////Activating of the first page
    //function rowDisplay(startIndex, endIndex) {
    //    $('#jar tr').hide().slice(startIndex, endIndex).show();
        
    //}
    //showPage(1);

    // Use event delegation, as these items are recreated later    
    $(document).on("click", ".pagination li.current-page:not(.active)", function () {
        return showPage(+$(this).text());

        //var pageNumber = $(this).text().trim();
        //savePage(tableId, pageNumber);

    });
    $("#next-page").on("click", function () {
        return showPage(currentPage + 1);
    });

    $("#previous-page").on("click", function () {
        return showPage(currentPage - 1);

    });


    



});


// save status of the page
// use the id of the table, in case multiple tables present
//function savePage(tableId, pageId) {
//    localStorage.setItem(tableId, pageId);
//}

//function LoadData(tableId) {
//    return localStorage.getItem(tableId);
//}

//function setPageId(tableId) {
//    var item = LoadData(tableId);

//    if (!item) {
//        return;
//    }

//    $(".active").removeClass("active");
//    var $pageButton = $('#pagination li:contains("' + item + '")');

//    if (!$pageButton) {
//        return;
//    }

//    var pageData = $pageButton.data();
//    rowDisplay(pageData.start, pageData.end);
//}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<div id="Tabledta"></div>
<div class="pagination"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following two methods,

1. `sessionStorage` [see the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

In your case I recommend `sessionStorage`, because the same will be active for the current session only. Save your latest page number to the sessionStorage. and after the page refresh check for the existence of the value in sessionStorage

```
var currentPage = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage');
if(!currentPage) {
 currentPage = 1;
}
showPage(currentPage);
```

---Save to sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.setItem('currentPage', page);
```

---get data from sessionStorage

```
var page = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage');
```

2. `localStorage` [See the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
   will be available even if the browser close.

Comment: yes I've already seen it, but how to implement it in my case, how can I take page number and reload it, that was a question...

Comment: You meen:                                                                                                                           
    localStorage.getItem('currentPage', page); and than paste it into  function showPage(whichPage)

Comment: not really get how to implement it, befor all, where should it be pasted and what with other pages?

Comment: Yes, like this var currentPage = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage');
if(!currentPage) {
 currentPage = 1;
}
showPage(currentPage);

Comment: something I'm doing wrong. maybe You can show me in jsfeedle or codepen what You mean

Comment: maybe as a separate function it will work? could You explain where do You think var currentPage = sessionStorage.getItem('currentPage'); if(!currentPage) { currentPage = 1; } showPage(currentPage); belong to?

Comment: I see the changes in Your feedle, but its not working, like before its Page #1 after reload and not the last page whaere i've been before reload....